# Adding a absolute path that has a \f in it

Tags: python

While adding an absolute path to my script because it has a \f in it the code won't run properly.

```
C:\Users\showoi\Desktop\website\repository\fileAdder\softwarelisting.xlsx
```

The file is in the same directory as the script but using a relative path won't work. No misspellings or anything.

Comment: Have you tried escaping your backslashes? Or a raw string?

Comment: Use forward slashes instead. There are a million dupes of this question.

Comment: sorry for not noticing the dupes, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Use python `r` string

```
path=r'C:\Users\showoi\Desktop\website\repository\fileAdder\softwarelisting.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following ways:

- `r"C:\Users\showoi\Desktop\website\repository\fileAdder\softwarelisting.xlsx"`
- `"C:\\Users\\showoi\\Desktop\\website\\repository\\fileAdder\\softwarelisting.xlsx"`
- `"C:/Users/showoi/Desktop/website/repository/fileAdder/softwarelisting.xlsx`